# How to position 3 images using HTML and CSS in the following way?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for the simplest method, to position three images in the following way using CSS and HTML

[image]

Image number 2 and 3 should be of 50% width and height of image number 1.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a grid to do so

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img:first-child {
  max-width: unset;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618326985678-88285545a9aa?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMDc5OTgyNA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618326985678-88285545a9aa?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMDc5OTgyNA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618326985678-88285545a9aa?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMDc5OTgyNA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#img1{
    grid-row: 1/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: red solid 1px;
  }
#img2{
  border: blue solid 1px;
}

#img3{
  border: green solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="img1"></div>
  <div id="img2"></div>
  <div id="img3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly go with Charles Lavalard's grid solution above, but wanted to show a flex solution that takes in that the images may not fit the designated space.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex; /* display side by side */
  align-items: stretch;  /* stretches the .right div */
}

.container img {
  object-fit: cover; /* clips image if it's too big */
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* fills out the width */
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.small {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* fills out the height */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="left large" src="https://picsum.photos/150/300">
  
  <div class="right">
    <img class="small" src="https://picsum.photos/300/100">
    <img class="small" src="https://picsum.photos/300/100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do this, but i think flex box is the right approach if you want to further align the text inside one of the divs.

A simple method will be to use 3 child divs and wrap it around 2 parent divs and finally 1 grandparent div. Use flex box with direction row on the grandparent div `content`. Then specify on `col2` to be flex-direction column.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

.third {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="first">lst</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="second">2nd</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
height:300px;
width:150px;
border:1px solid white
}
.rows {
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
.container {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
}
.rows img{
height:150px;
width: 75px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/40/49/cityscape-vertical-3-vector-19094049.jpg">
  <div class="rows">
<img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/40/49/cityscape-vertical-3-vector-19094049.jpg">
<img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/40/49/cityscape-vertical-3-vector-19094049.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```